# I did a query in access that calculates a date, when I enter the date in a form I get the result in the query but not able to save it to the table

Tags: ms-access

[Pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZbol.png)I am new to MS Access. I have a customer table with creationdate field as well as submissiondate. The submissiondate was calculated via a query since it carries multiple conditions. I created a form from the customer table where I am able to input the creationdate field and I managed to show the submissiondate (from the query) via Dlookup but the date is not recorded in the customer table. How can I record the submissiondate value from the query in the customer table without having to do an update query every time I add a new customer? I did an update query but it updates all records every time it runs, and we have more than 50K customers. Any help is appreciated.

this is the query in Access that gets the result for me.

SELECT HardDeadlineCalculationQ1.ID, HardDeadlineCalculationQ1.R AS ReferralDate, HardDeadlineCalculationQ1.[Source of Referral], HardDeadlineCalculationQ1.HD1, HardDeadlineCalculationQ1.wdhd1, HardDeadlineCalculationQ1.hd2, HardDeadlineCalculationQ1.wdhd2, HolidaysT.holidaydates, Switch([HardDeadlineCalculationQ1].hd2=holidayst.holidaydates,"Yes") AS isholiday, IIf(isholiday="Yes",([HardDeadlineCalculationQ1.hd2]-1),[HardDeadlineCalculationQ1].hd2) AS hd3, WeekdayName(Weekday(hd3)) AS wdhd3, Switch(WeekdayName(Weekday(hd3))="Monday",(hd3),WeekdayName(Weekday(hd3))="Tuesday",(hd3),WeekdayName(Weekday(hd3))="Wednesday",(hd3),WeekdayName(Weekday(hd3))="Thursday",(hd3),WeekdayName(Weekday(hd3))="Friday",(hd3),WeekdayName(Weekday(hd3))="Sunday",(hd3-2)) AS hd4, WeekdayName(Weekday(hd4)) AS wdhd4
FROM HardDeadlineCalculationQ1 LEFT JOIN HolidaysT ON HardDeadlineCalculationQ1.hd2 = HolidaysT.holidaydates;

regards,

Comment: You don't. You use a _select query_, not the table, as source for the form, and either let the query or the form calculate the submission date to be displayed.

Comment: thanks for your response. but i need to save the submissiondate in the table to run reports later with the rest of the information in that table.

Comment: OK, but then use the query as source for the report - or let the report do the calculation.

Comment: thanks. will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The submissiondate was calculated via a query since it carries multiple conditions"

By this, i presume you mean that the submission date is a calculated field(as its control source)

Do the following
Copy the calculation, i.e formula and put in vba code, under the after update event of every field that is a variable in the expression.
e.g submissiondate= place the formular here

Then on the form  remove the calculation , i.e formula from the control source of the form control and make a field in the table the control source, e.g submissiondate.

Comment: hello, thank you for your response but it was not calculated via control source. It was calculated via a query. I updated the question to include the query. see above.

Comment: the query above is a different but i have different field with a similar issue, so it is the same result. in that case i input the referral date and i calculated the hd4. i want to record that value in the customer table. since it is a query i can not put it in the AfterUpdate event.

Comment: The submission date's row source is the query above, you can put a value returned by a query into the after update event. can you share an image that will clarify the type of control that is used for the submission date, i believe its a text box?

Comment: Hello, i just added the pic of the form on top (body of the question). thank you for your help!!!!

Comment: So the dlookup  where in the form is it placed in, please share screen or type answer here, its very likely my earlier suggestion of puting it in vba code is the way forward. Do answer the question i just asked.

Comment: the Dlookup was in the harddeadline field, i just removed it because it was slowing the form when jumping through customers. =DLookUp("Hd4","HardDeadlineCalculationQ2","id = " & [ID])
The dlookup, did not record the value displayed in the customer table. it is only to show the value, and i need it to be saved in the customer table, that is where the form is tied to.

Comment: So place the Dlookup function into the after update field of the control that triggers it. what is the control that after entering the value, the dlookup function calculates based on it? is it ID field on the form?  So under the after update event  of the ID field you can write me.submissiondate=DLookUp("Hd4","HardDeadlineCalculationQ2","id = " & [ID])

Comment: i placed the Dlookup in the Referral receipt date (creationdate) field in the after update event like you told me. (me.submissiondate=DLookUp("Hd4","HardDeadlineCalculationQ2","id = " & [ID])). now every time i update the Referral receipt date (creationdate), it updates the harddeadline (submissiondate) field in the customer table. this is awesome!!!!